# Is this a basis for 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am completely lost. I tried getting help, but this doesn't make sense.

$2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

How do I prove a basis for this?

I've seen all the $a_1 v_1+a_2 v_2+ \cdots + a_n v_n$ not equal to zero linearly independent stuff, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you know what a basis is?

Comment: That is my problem. I need someone to help me understand it.

Comment: Make sure you know the definitions of the following terms: Linear independence, linear combination, spanning set, basis. The definitions should be in your textbook. It's really up to you to spend the time reading to make sure you know what all of these terms mean.

Comment: instead of thinking of 2x2 matrices, think of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ of the form $(a,b,-b,a)$.  Then notice that there is a one to one correspondence between vectors of that form and matrices of the form you described earlier.

Comment: The kicker is to notice that the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb R$ forms a vector space over $\Bbb R,$ in that it satisfies all the [axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) of such a structure. It's true that we may not typically think of arbitrary matrices as vectors, but in that sense, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b  \\
-b & a  \\
\end{array} \right] $=$\,\,a\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{array} \right]$+$b \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1  \\
-1 & 0  \\
\end{array} \right]$

Comment: That means those two are basis vectors, but it doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Ok. You need to show that these form a basis i.e. these are linear independent and these span the original set (i.e. each set of matrices of the form $(a\,\, ,b\,\, ,-b\,\,, a)$ can be written as the linear combination of the two matrices) which is evident in the hint. For linear independence, you need to show that if the RHS becomes $0$ (here the zero $2\times 2$ matrix), then $a=0$ and $b=0$.